# Weird behaviour when trying to estimate an unknown variable

Tags: python, statistics

I'm trying to estimate an unknown variable (p) with a very high precision. What I have is a large number of ordered values (I call them t-values). Each value has a sequence number (n). Each of those t-values is basically the result of multiplying n with p and then adding a random offset ("noise"). My idea is to simply order the t-values according to their sequence number and then take the mean of all the offsets. It works very well. Here are 10 examples of estimates (true p is 1.0 and the number of t-values is 100000):

```
1.0000737485173519
0.9999987583319258
1.0000688058361697
1.0002021529901506
0.9999391175701831
1.000012370796987
0.9999891218161053
1.0001566049086157
0.9999818309412788
0.9999594118399372
```

Close enough for what I want.

But in practice, a certain amount of t-values will also be lost. If I introduce a random loss of t-values the precision goes down dramatically, even if the number of lost t-values is as low as 0.001% - 0.01% and, this is the weird part, even if I compensate by generating more t-values so the number of t-values used in calculating the mean is the same!

Here are 10 examples when about 1% of the values were dropped:

```
1.0024257205135292
1.0019969333070318
1.0019520792036436
1.001061555944925
0.997728342781954
1.000205614588305
0.9964173869854615
1.0028314864552466
1.0014389330965119
0.9954499027939065
```

Why is this?

I have made a simulation in Python to demonstrate. To see the difference, first run it as is. Then change drop_probability to 0.01 and run again.

Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import random

random.seed(42)

runs = 10
effective_number_of_values = 100000

real_period=1
static_offset=0.5
lambd=0.2

drop_probability=0.00000001
#drop_probability=0.0001
#drop_probability=0.001
#drop_probability=0.01
#drop_probability=0.1
#drop_probability=0.5


for run in range(0, runs):
    values = []
    dropped_ts = 0

    last_was_dropped = False
    num_values = 0
    n = 1
    t = 0
    while num_values < effective_number_of_values + 1:

        actual_t = t
        noise = static_offset + random.expovariate(lambd)
        effective_t = actual_t + noise

        if drop_probability is not None and \
            random.random() <= drop_probability:

            values.append((n, effective_t, True))
            dropped_ts += 1
            last_was_dropped = True
        else:
            values.append((n, effective_t, False))
            if not last_was_dropped:
                num_values += 1
            last_was_dropped = False

        t += real_period
        n += 1

    values.sort()

    last_n = 0
    last_t = 0
    last_was_dropped = False
    avg_sum = 0
    avg_n = 0
    for v in values:
            n, t, dropped = v

            if n > 1:
                    if not dropped and not last_was_dropped:
                        avg_sum += t - last_t
                        avg_n += 1

            last_t = t
            last_n = n
            last_was_dropped = dropped

    print(avg_sum / avg_n, "(values used: %d, dropped along the way: %.2f%% (%d))" % (avg_n, (dropped_ts/len(values))*100, dropped_ts))
                         <br>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `last_was_dropped`?

Comment: Check the length of your `values` variable. It does not seem to be equal to the sum of values used length and values dropped length.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how have you determined that this margin of error is unexpected? While attempting to answer your question, I saw that you had a Poisson distribution (expovariate) which has a very different margin for error than you might expect if you based calculations upon a normal distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is due to the nature of your sampling. As you increase the percentage chance of dropping values, the overall percentage of dropped values will increase *exponentially* and will drastically reduce your accuracy and precision.

Needless to say, such a significant change in the sampling population causes your measurements to become exponentially more imprecise as the percentage of lost samples increases. As you increase the population, this problem becomes less apparent. If you expect more values to be dropped, take a much larger sample. If your means of sampling is so inaccurate that it loses more than ~10% of samples, then you must either rectify this problem which causes reduced accuracy by dropping less samples, taking significantly more, or reconsidering whether you need less than 1% variance in your estimations.

Much of this is rooted in statistical theory. A cursory study of probabilities and random sampling will yield many helpful equations and rules of thumb to help ensure accurate estimates of unknown parameters.

The primary equation you'll need to use for this purpose is the one calculating the Margin of Error for a Normal Distribution to represent your sampling method: `ME = z * sqrt( (p_hat * q_hat) / n)`.

You will also need the Margin of Error for a Poisson distribution to represent the error introduced by the noise: the [formula, given large values of n*lambd](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-to-calculate-a-confidence-level-for-a-poisson-distribution) is `ME = z * sqrt( lambd / n )`. You'll need to include this value in your total error after sampling, and with 95% confidence, 10,000 samples, and lambd of 0.2, you find that it goes as high as `0.45%`, explaining a large proportion of the unexpected error.

However, this method of determining margin for error of the Poisson distribution is only a crude approximation that treats it as if it were a normal distribution. In your situation, with such a small lambd, you may wish to consider one of the 19 approximations contained within [this paper](https://www.ine.pt/revstat/pdf/rs120203.pdf).

### In Summary

It does appear that you are correct about losing accuracy (assuming a normal distribution), however it may be due to the use of `random.expovariate(lambd)`:

> "Exponential distribution... Returned values range from 0 to positive infinity if lambd is positive."

Using a mean function will *not* yield a valid result because such a low value of `u=0.2` for a Poisson distribution (basically what expovariate is) will be non-symmetrical, as is attested by [W.R.Leo](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Leo/Stats2_2.html) of CalTech:

> Note that the distribution is not symmetric. The peak or maximum of the distribution **does not, therefore, correspond to the mean.** However, as µ becomes large, the distribution becomes more and more symmetric and approaches a Gaussian form.

Comment: Thank you. It seems like a need to take a radically different approach. Eiether it's simply not possible to do it like this, or it requires a bit more knownledge of statistics than I possess.

Comment: @jogc It's normal as a programmer to realize there are things you need to study to solve a new problem. Usually it's math, statistics, or logic. Sometimes even music, art, or physics. You're doing fine and with the current settings, you should be able to get within 2% of the real value. Statistics can help you measure and reason about your accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your question, but I'm trying to be helpful.

I do believe the result your seeing is to be expected. Suppose the drop rate increase such that in average every second measurement is dropped. The average difference between two consecutive remaining measurements will be twice the value it had been before. So the drop rate does affect the result. Similarly, If you drop just 10%, then the difference should increase by ~10%.

Here is the way I rewrote your code. In this version I always drop a fixed amount of measurements using the `random.sample` function.

```
import random

#random.seed(42)

effective_number_of_values = 100000

real_period = 1
static_offset = 0.5
lambd = 0.2

drop_probabilities = [0.00001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 0.99]

values = []
t = 0
for drop_probability in drop_probabilities:
    desiredlen = round(effective_number_of_values * (1 + drop_probability))

    for t in range(desiredlen):
        noise = static_offset + random.expovariate(lambd)
        effective_t = t + noise
        values.append((t, effective_t))

    values_after_drop = random.sample(values, effective_number_of_values)
    values_after_drop.sort()

    diff_t = [values_after_drop[i][1] - values_after_drop[i-1][1]
              for i in range(1, len(values_after_drop))]

    avg = sum(diff_t)/len(diff_t)

    print("avg = {}. {} dropped out of {} at {} probability".
          format(avg, len(values) - effective_number_of_values,
                 len(values), drop_probability))
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness here is the actual problem I'm trying to solve:

Two computers are connected to the internet.
Computer A is sending a special kind of packets to computer B with a fixed interval (the packets are based on UDP). Computer B needs to estimate what this interval is with very high accuracy.

The packets have sequence numbers. Each packet will obviously be more or less delayed and some will be lost. Some will arrive in the wrong order.

So what computer B knows is this: the list of arrived packets with their sequence numbers and the time they arrived. From that I hoped it would be possible to estimate the interval with at least four decimals accuracy, with not more than around 10000 samples (since I want to account for small fluctuations in the clock of the computers during the day and a typical interval will be 1 second I dont want to use more than that). I hoped this would be possible even with a high rate of lost packets (for example 50%).

Comment: What about this alternative: include an accurate timestamp in each packet from computer A. Or you could have a handshake to determine the interval (like how microcontrollers choose the baud rate to speak with unknown serial devices). I suggest this because your wording implies that computer A is also in your control. This question is an example of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).